# Using std::find_if with std::vector to find smallest element greater than some value

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

I have a vector of doubles which are ordered.

```
std::vector<double> vec;
for(double x{0.0}; x < 10.0 + 0.5; x += 1.0) vec.push_back(x);
```

I am trying to use `std::find_if` to find the first element, and its corresponding index, of this vector for which `y < element`. Where `y` is some value.

For example, if `y = 5.5` then the relevant element is element `6.0` which has index `6`, and is the 7th element.

I suspect that a lambda function could be used do to this.

- Can a lambda function be used to do this?
- If so, how do I implement a `find_if` statement to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

1 line of code is necessary, if a lambda function is used: `x` is a local double (value we are searching for) `const double x = 5.5`

```
std::find_if(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [x] (double element) { return (x < element); })
```

Breaking this down, we have:

```
std::find_if(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), lambda)
```

The lambda is:

```
[x] (double element) { return (x < element); }
```

This means:

- capture the local variable `x` for use inside the lambda body
- the lambda function takes a single `double` as an argument (the algorithm `find_if` will pass each element as it iterates over the vector to this function as `element`)
- the function body returns true when the first element is found for which `x < element`

Note: I answered this question myself while researching possible solutions. The context in which I am using this in my own program is slightly different. In my context, the vector is a specification for numerical boundries, and I am looking to find `lower < x < higher`. Therefore the code I used is slightly different to this, in that I had to shift my returned iterator by 1 place because of how the numerical boundries are specified. If I introduced a bug in transcribing the solution, let me know.

Comment: Note that, `std::find_if` returns an iterator. In order to get the index, you can use `std::distance(vec.cbegin(), it)`, which is O(1) operation for vector's random access iterators (but would be O(n) if the vector is changed to e.g. `std::list`).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::upper_bound()` - it is more effective (it is using binary search) and does not need a lambda:

```
auto it = std::upper_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), x );
```

if you need to find `lower < x < upper` you can use `std::equal_range()`, but you would need additional logic to find proper `lower` as `std::lower_bound` will give element which less or equal to `x`, so you need to make sure `lower` is less than `x` and not equal.

[live example](https://ideone.com/AjwdqG)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't been introduced to [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) yet:

```
std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need the index, you can add a counter.

Something like

```
x = 5;

cnt = -1;

std::find_if(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(),
   [&] (double element) { ++cnt; return (x < element); })
```

Comment: This is not guarantied to work, and has overhead. std::distance is preferable.

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer - why do you say that is not guarantied to work? And do you think `std::distance` is preferable for `std::vector` (where is O(1)) or also for `std::list` (where is O(n))?